# Index on JSON Array Field

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

I have a JSON field that is an array of elements composed of oid, instance and value. Most of my queries will be on a combination of oid and instance.

What is the syntax for creating such an index if the combination of oid and instance is unique?

```
[
 { 'oid' : '1.3.1', 'instance' : '0', 'value' : '0' }, 
 { 'oid' : '1.3.1', 'instance' : '2', 'value' : '9' },
 { 'oid' : '1.3.6.1', 'instance' : '0', 'value' : '1' },
 { 'oid' : '1.3.6.9', 'instance' : '0', 'value' : '1' }
]
```

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406269/create-index-on-json-field-in-postgresql-9-2 the answer there is to index whole JSON text.

Comment: Please provide version of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Create full-text index and search for substring.
Another option would be to use intermediate indexed table that keeps parsed values and points to the one with JSON.